# Find Graphics Card/Driver Details

Tags: 13.04, ati, graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04. How can I check that I have a driver for my graphics card installed and see details about it?

Comment: @Mark - Sorry but I tried to add this as a comment my reputation does not allow.. you can get glxinfo through mesa-utils so `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` .. though I think that Ubuntu will at least point you in that direction if you try and install glxinfo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `glxinfo` (form the *meta-utils* package) for information about your driver and OpenGL.
Run

> glxinfo | grep OpenGL

for info about your driver and OpenGL.

You can use `lspci` for info about your PCI devices (so, VGA too).
Use

> lspci -v -s `lspci | awk '/VGA/{print $1}'`

for info about you video card.

Comment: `glxinfo` isn't installed on my system and it's not in `apt-get`, but the 2nd command worked well. Thank you.

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` to install `glxinfo`

Answer (score 2):

Follow `System Settings` - `Software & Updates` - `Additional Drivers`

Comment: I prefer this solution to either `glxinfo` or `lspci` because this actually tells you what driver is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type :

1. `lspci`
2. `lshw`

It will all the details of your drivers.