# Newly upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 - slow?

Tags: 14.04

Have been running Ubuntu 10/Puppy Linux - excellent performance. Just replaced it with 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04. PC has 1.5MB RAM. I am now experiencing Very slow performance. Is this due to 14.04's size and complexity? Or something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- First of all check your graphic card details using command given on [Find Graphics Card/Driver Details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348308/find-graphics-card-driver-details)
- The RAM you specified in question should be 1.5 GB not in MB ,you can check RAM size by clicking on system settings> details or search in your dash for RAM details.
- Basically this problem occurs with old graphic cards , you can have a look at what kind of divers and graphic card ubuntu supports [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) or [Unity Graphics Requirement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequiremens) .
- The solution as proposed on ubuntu askubuntu website and many other dissussion formus is that:

  - Either install Light weight versions of ubuntu like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.
  - After installing ubuntu try for ubuntu 2D, thats works fine for me.